# Double integrals, Tonelli Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am doing some problems on double Lebesgue integrals and I have one doubt.
Let's say I have

$f: (a,b) \times \mathbb{R}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and I can prove that 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x,y)| dy < \infty \ \  \ \ \ \forall x\in (a,b)$$

Then can I just conclude that as $(a,b)$ is bounded we will have

$$\int_{(a,b)}\int _{\mathbb{R}} |f(x,y)| dy\   dx < \infty $$ 
and hence by Tonelli theorem that $f\in  (L((a,b) \times \mathbb{R})   $ ?

Sorry if the question is trivial, thank you very much!!

Comment: I am sorry for my hasty comment. You need to show two things before using Tonelli theorem. First You should show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x,y)|dy$ is a measurable function and secondly you should show it is integrable, that is the the integral of this function over $(a,b)$ should be finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $g(x)=\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x,y)| \mathrm dy$ is finite for every $x$ in $(a,b)$ does not imply that  $\displaystyle\int_{(a,b)}\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x,y)| \mathrm dy\mathrm dx=\int_{(a,b)}g(x)\mathrm dx$ is finite hence the result you are trying to prove does not hold in general.